# Modernizr download file, but it is still undefined afterwards? (Only in IE9 after page postback)

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I've got a jQuery plugin I made which will nicely format dates on elements with certain attributes on them.  Overall it works, but I'm having some problems with Modernizr, but ONLY in IE and ONLY after a form postback.

Here's a snippet from the plugin where it uses the fantastic [MomentJS library](http://momentjs.com/).  Basically the first time the plugin is called, it will download the needed file then run the code to parse dates.  If it is called any time afterwards and the library has already been downloaded, it can just go ahead and run the date parsing code.

```
function parseDates() {
    var $items = this;

    if (typeof moment !== "undefined") {
        //If we are calling this at a time after page load, just run the function
        setupDisplayDate();

    } else {
        //If the files have not been included yet, download them & call the function
        //Load in a date library!
        Modernizr.load({
            load: SCRIPTS_PATH + "moment.min.js",
            callback: setupDisplayDate
        });
    }

    function setupDisplayDate() {
        console.log("setupDisplayDate called! Moment is " + typeof moment);
        $items.each(function () {
            var $thisItem = $(this);

            var formatter = $thisItem.data("date-format") || "MMMM Do, YYYY";
            var ticks = parseInt($thisItem.data("date-ticks"), 10);
            var formattedDate = moment(ticks).format(formatter);
            $thisItem.text(formattedDate);
        });
    }
}
```

When I do this in IE9 only after a page postback, I get an error within the `setupDisplayDate` function saying that moment is not defined.  What am I doing wrong?

I did find that if I do a timeout of 500ms it will work, but I shouldn't have to do that.  I thought the whole point of the `Modernizr.load` feature was to download the code, and then make it available.  It seems to download it and the fire my callback before it is available to use.

---

## EDIT

Here's [a blog post about how IE9 will not properly dynamically added scripts: http://www.guypo.com/technical/ies-premature-execution-problem/

Any way around this?

---

## Another Edit

It seems like the issues is actually regarding multiple calls to the `load` function and then the various callbacks firing out of order.  There's an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/issues/113) about it and [this reproducible test case](http://jsfiddle.net/unlimit/S27Kz/).

Comment: _It seems to download it and the fire my callback before it is available to use_ - Fact or assumption?

Comment: In the `setupDisplayDate` function, the `console.log(typeof moment)` returns `undefined` in IE9 after a postback.

Comment: Sure, but the question is has the script been loaded at this moment? I'm asking because there could be some weird behavior of IE that is not yet known to the developers of yepnope.js, so it would be good to know if the script has not been loaded or not been executed so far.

Comment: Read my last paragraph, but inside the callback I can add a 500ms delay before I call the function, and then it works.  This is fragile and I shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Ah sorry, now I see what you are asking.  No, I am unsure if the script has actually been downloaded or not at this point.  I was assuming it was since Modernizr fired my callback function.